# Unable to run v.clean in QGIS 3.0.1 in Python console

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, grass-7.0

I am trying to use v.clean algorithm in QGIS 3 python console. Code is as follows.

```
    lyr = iface.activeLayer()
    new_layer = lyr.materialize(QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterFids(lyr.selectedFeatureIds()))
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(new_layer)

    alg = 'grass7:v.clean'

    extent = new_layer.extent()
    xmin = extent.xMinimum()
    xmax = extent.xMaximum()
    ymin = extent.yMinimum()
    ymax = extent.yMaximum()

    params = {"input": new_layer, "type": 1, "tool": 0, "-b": True, "-c": True,
              "output": "E:/out.shp", "error": "E:/errLayer.shp",
              "GRASS_REGION_PARAMETER": "%f,%f,%f,%f" % (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax),
              "GRASS_SNAP_TOLERANCE_PARAMETER": 5, "GRASS_MIN_AREA_PARAMETER": 5,
              "GRASS_OUTPUT_TYPE_PARAMETER": 2}

    test = processing.run(alg, params)
```

When I run this code I get following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.0\apps\qgis\python\plugins\splitroads\Split_Roads.py", line 211, in run
    test = processing.run(alg, params)
    File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.0\apps\qgis\python\plugins\processing\tools\general.py", line 84, in run
    return Processing.runAlgorithm(algOrName, parameters, onFinish, feedback, context)
    File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.0\apps\qgis\python\plugins\processing\core\Processing.py", line 189, in runAlgorithm
    feedback.reportError(msg)
    TypeError: reportError() missing 1 required positional argument: 'fatal_error'
```

I have also checked input parameters of v.clean algorithm by using

```
   processing.algorithmHelp("grass7:v.clean")
```

and got following output

```
   Input parameters:

   input:  <QgsProcessingParameterVectorLayer>
           Layer to clean
   type:  <QgsProcessingParameterEnum>
          Input feature type
          0 - point
          1 - line
          2 - boundary
          3 - centroid
          4 - area
          5 - face
          6 - kernel
    tool: <QgsProcessingParameterEnum>
          Cleaning tool
          0 - break
          1 - snap
          2 - rmdangle
          3 - chdangle
          4 - rmbridge
          5 - chbridge
          6 - rmdupl
          7 - rmdac
          8 - bpol
          9 - prune
          10 - rmarea
          11 - rmline
          12 - rmsa
   threshold: <QgsProcessingParameterString>
              Threshold (comma separated for each tool)
   -b:  <QgsProcessingParameterBoolean>
        Do not build topology for the output vector
   -c:  <QgsProcessingParameterBoolean>
        Combine tools with recommended follow-up tools
   output:  <QgsProcessingParameterVectorDestination>
            Cleaned
   error:  <QgsProcessingParameterVectorDestination>
    Errors
   GRASS_REGION_PARAMETER:  <QgsProcessingParameterExtent>
    GRASS GIS 7 region extent
   GRASS_SNAP_TOLERANCE_PARAMETER:  <QgsProcessingParameterNumber>
    v.in.ogr snap tolerance (-1 = no snap)
   GRASS_MIN_AREA_PARAMETER:  <QgsProcessingParameterNumber>
    v.in.ogr min area
   GRASS_OUTPUT_TYPE_PARAMETER:  <QgsProcessingParameterEnum>
   v.out.ogr output type
    0 - auto
    1 - point
    2 - line
    3 - area

   Outputs:

   output:  <QgsProcessingOutputVectorLayer>
     Cleaned
   error:  <QgsProcessingOutputVectorLayer>
     Errors
```

Everything seems fine but I am unable to run it.Can you please let me know how to run v.clean successfully in python console using QGIS 3?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears that it was due to some bug I updated to latest version 3.0.2 of QGIS and modified processing.py to import QgsProcessingFeedback as follows

```
from qgis.core import (QgsMessageLog,
                   QgsApplication,
                   QgsMapLayer,
                   QgsProcessingProvider,
                   QgsProcessingAlgorithm,
                   QgsProcessingException,
                   QgsProcessingParameterDefinition,
                   QgsProcessingOutputVectorLayer,
                   QgsProcessingOutputRasterLayer,
                   QgsProcessingOutputMapLayer,
                   QgsProcessingOutputMultipleLayers,
                   QgsProcessingFeedback)
```

and everything is working fine now.